# Benefit of threaded binary tree

Tags: c, stack, binary-tree

In the documentation of threaded binary tree, I read

> Both the recursive and non-recursive procedures for binary tree traversal require that pointers to all of the free nodes be kept temporarily on stack. This can be avoided by using threaded binary tree

My question is

1- How and when the pointers are kept in stack in Normal Binary Tree?

2- How the pointers are not added in stack in Threaded Binary Tree?

Comment: Have you looked at how a normal binary tree works? Also, where is this threaded binary tree you mention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) They are talking about walking the tree.  You either use a recusrive algorithm (which uses the CPU stack to keep track of things for you), or you use an iterative approach and keep a data structure stack  and manage the nodes you need to visit yourself.  The latter may perform better because you eliminate the overhead of the function calls, but it is often more conceptually difficult to understand.

2) A threaded tree keeps stores the information of how to walk the tree in the tree itself (instead of NULL pointers that you have to backtrack they point to the next location in the tree to walk), this allows you to walk the tree "in a straight line", so no stack is needed.

The [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree)  does a pretty good job of showing this.

-A